# Proper way to serialize POJO to JSON/XML for use in JSP

Tags: java, json, jsp, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement this use case in a RESTful manner in my Spring MVC application. Imagine having a POJO called SalesReport with a list of Sales. Using content negotiation I'm able to return the XML and JSON representations. For example...

```
 <SalesReport>
     <Sale>...</Sale>
 </SalesReport>
```

For my HTML representation it needs to be sexier, of course. The requirement is to display a  chart using Highcharts as well as the data in table format. Pretty standard stuff. I am unsure of how to accomplish this in an elegant way. I thought about

1. Serializing SalesReport to an XML/JSON formatted String and doing `request.setAttribute()`. I feel like this couples my controller with my view. My XML and JSON representations don't need this.
2. Making an AJAX call to get the data after the JSP loads. This seems wasteful to make another HTTP request and my data is not cached either.
3. Create util class with functions that uses Spring MVC's JSON and XML libs to return the serialized format I need. Then in the JSP do something like `<%= RestUtil.toJSON(salesReport) %>`. This way my controller doesn't know specifics about my HTML view and I'm not sending extra HTTP calls.

What is a good approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use JSON/XML in the JSP? Using content-negotiation text/html should correspond with a controller method. You can access the POJO directly with the [spring-form tld](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html) or [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) in the jsp.

Assuming you have the view resolver set up:

```
@RequestMapping("salesreport")
public String getSalesReport(ModelMap model) {
   model.addAttribute("reports", salesReportService.findAll());
   return "reports/view";
}
```

In reports/view.jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="reports" var="report">
   Field 1: ${report.field1} <br/>
   Field 2: ${report.field2}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I won't be using XML/JSON directly but passing it into Highcharts, a JS charting library.